# Scope of Salesforce Shield

Tags: shield-encryption, shield

When you license Salesforce Shield is it at the org level? I’m having trouble determining this answer. Based on what I can see via TrailHead, this should apply to any data within the org including any custom fields. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Shield is licensed at the org level

Based on your tag - I'm limiting myself to Shield Platform Encryption in the rest of my answer

- Shield encryption applies to whatever OOTB and custom Object fields are encryptable. You decide on a field-by-field basis. There is no blanket encryption across all fields/records.
- Encrypting certain OOTB fields may run into issues if you have some managed packages that violate usage requirements for encrypted fields (Current version of Mass Action Scheduler is one such package)
- Encrypting certain fields may cause you to have to redesign your application in order to avoid encryption restrictions (e.g. no SOQL ORDER BY or LIKE on encrypted fields; certain restrictions on formula fields that do string operations like MID or FIND)

Comment: are user licenses in any way involved here? Do you have to pay anything per user license?

Comment: Yes, it is an add-on per org.  The bigger the org, the bigger the price.   Discounts may be available

Comment: Hey @cropredy thanks for replying :) - I guess where I’m struggling is if users are even relevant - it seems it’s a percentage of spend - https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/platform/shield/ (I just stumbled on to this today even after previous searching).  I guess let me ask this a different way - let’s say I pay for Shield as evidenced by the link, and decide to build a custom app or install a managed package on Salesforce for my org, using custom objects etc., wouldn’t that new package or app I built or bought have immediate access to Shield features ie the option to encrypt?

Comment: Percentage of spend is a f(#users,Edition).   Your customer would need to be a Shield licensee before they could use your product.